# how do I pass all the files in a folder to shell script and get result in one file?

Tags: shell

I have a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`grep "var lon" $1 | tr -d 'var longitude=;'`
b=`grep "var lat" $1 | tr -d 'var latitude=;'`
echo "$1,$a,$b";
```

I have around 100 files with latitude and longtude. which i pass through this script to get it. like
place,lat,lon . where place is file name.
now i would like to pass all the file to the script at one shot and get all the lat lons in one file.
how do I do this ? for  eg: one output for `sh script.sh aus`

```
aus,10.20,20.20
```

now i am looking to pass all the 100 files and get 100 such lines in one single file.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your script to accept multiple arguments like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg in "$@"
do
 a=`grep "var lon" "$arg" | tr -d 'var longitude=;'`
 b=`grep "var lat" "$arg" | tr -d 'var latitude=;'`
 echo "$arg,$a,$b"
done
```

Now you can pass in whichever files you like. You can even use wildcards. Here are a few examples:

```
# only aus
$ script.sh aus 

# two files
$ script.sh aus usa

# all files beginning with a
$ script.sh a*

# all files in the current directory
# the output is written to output.txt
$ script.sh * > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't code `bash` off the top of my head very well, but you can loop through all the files and append the output to a file via `>>`:

```
touch output.txt

for file in *
do
  a=`grep "var lon" $file | tr -d 'var longitude=;'`
  b=`grep "var lat" $file | tr -d 'var latitude=;'`
  echo "$file,$a,$b" >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: where are you passing the name of files ? just confused ? my all the files are in a single folder. echo is having 3 arguments in above scripts. ur scrip shows just two. where is the file argument ? please corrent me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was just for debug. I added it back in. This script reads all of the names of all of the files in the folder (top-level, so non-recursive).

Comment: -1: don't quote the asterisk. You're looping over one file, literally named "*"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call grep twice:

```
awk -F '[=;]' '
  $1 ~ /var longitude/ {lon = $2}
  $1 ~ /var latitude/ {lat = $2}
  END {print FILENAME, lon, lat}
' filename
```

then

```
get_coords() {
  awk -F '[=;]' '
    $1 ~ /var longitude/ {lon = $2}
    $1 ~ /var latitude/ {lat = $2}
    END {print FILENAME, lon, lat}
  ' "$1"
}
for file; do get_coords "$file"; done
```

If you have GNU awk on your system, you only need to call gawk once:

```
gawk -F '[=;]' '
  $1 ~ /var longitude/ {lon = $2}
  $1 ~ /var latitude/ {lat = $2}
  ENDFILE {print FILENAME, lon, lat}
' "$@"
```